# Help with URL Rewrite

Tags: php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page that selects some info from a database
and displays it with a link to a second page that uses
the result to query the database, something like this:

```
$sel=mysql_query("select id, title from thetable ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$title=$row['title'];
echo "<a href='more.php?id=$id'>$title</a>";
}
```

The issue is, in the more.php page, instead of more.php?id=5 to show in
the address bar, I want something like more/title

Secondly, as it obtains in most sites, I want the link on the referring page
to show this friendly url on mouse hover not the more.php?id=5

And I notice in most sites some words like 'a', 'and', 'the' etc are usually
removed from the url title(even if there originally), moreover how does one
handle the situation where more than one record have the same title.

How does one go about achieving this url rewrite with htaccess or whatever
method is used?

Comment: By "mouse hover" do you mean the "tool tip" or the URL display in the status bar (Lower left corner in some browsers)? If you want the URL in the address bar to display "My Page" instead of "id=5" you will have to rename the page you are linking to ("My_Page.php"). You might just use a user friendly hyperlink instead. Maybe an example of what you are doing and why you need the URL to be user friendly will help get you better answers?

Answer (score 1):

First create a PHP function that generates friendly URLs.  Something like this would work, adjust to your liking.

```
function friendlyURL($id, $title) {

    $string = $title;
    $paramcount = func_num_args();
    for ($i = 2; $i < $paramcount; $i++) {
        $string .= "-" . func_get_arg($i);
    }
    $string = preg_replace('`&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;`i', '-', $string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "utf-8");
    $string = preg_replace("`&([a-z]+);`i", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("`['\[\]]`", "", $string);

    $string = preg_replace(array("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "`[-]+`"), "-", $string);

    $string = trim($string, '-');
    return trim($id . "-" . $string, '-');
}
```

Next call the function in code replace your echo with this.

```
echo "<a href='/more/".friendlyURL($id, $title)."/'>$title</a>";
```

Next use a rewrite rule like.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^more/([0-9]+)[^/]*/?$ more.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have a structure similar to this:

www.website.com/products/1/this-is-my-product-title

where 1 is the ID of your product

htaccess rule would be:

```
^products/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ more.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

In order to make a clean url you should look up str_replace or regular expressions.
(For example replace all spaces with '-', remove all weird char etc)
In addition to this, you should make sure that the title part matches the real title of the ID, and make sure the file more.php is not accessed typing more.php in URL (look into super variable $_SERVER).